# Media queries for breakpoints are effective only if touch simulation is on

Tags: css, media-queries, touch, screen, responsive

I applied some media queries to my css. These appear to be effective only when browsing the website from the devices I designed them for, or when - while using the browser Responsive Design Mode - the touch simulation is turned on.
If I simply drag the screen to reduce its size, the website doesn't appear to be responsive.

Any idea on why is happening?

These are the queries I'm using:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Style */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Style */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
  /* Style */
}
```

And here you can see the website GH repo:
https://bianchinicecilia.github.io/ceciliabianchini/index.html

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Internet Explorer 11, still in Windows 10, will work excellent from 240px and up when you change the view of the browser. This works **without** using the developer mode of IE11. I use it only for responsive look & feel, not for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! 
Working on a Mac, I'm happy with either Firefox or Chrome. I actually do use the dev mode with no touch, and usually things work alright. 
This time I started to design the queries by reducing the screen size but then, when opening the repo from my phone, the design looked messed up in a weird way, so I had to redo the work with the touch simulation on. That way it worked.

Comment: My experience on Windows: Firefox does not have a real responsive test tool in "responsive design modus". Chrome and Opera are much better for this in DevTools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I can help you.

You're using deprecated media queries. You don't need to use -device-, just min-width or max-width. I also noticed that your site is without the viewport meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. This is very important too!

Finally, review all meta tags because some sizes are conflicting.

**List of media queries:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

**About Viewport**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts

Comment: This is all very on point, thanks! I'll try what you suggested and get back ASAP.

Comment: Ok, you were right!! :)) But to solve the touch simulation when on dev mode + make the smallest queries working on the phone, I had to use this viewport line: 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

The one you suggested worked only when on iPad. Thanks again, also for the links, you've been very kind!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing this too!

Comment: Okay, I was wondering why my code wasn't working. Thank you!!